# Smtp mail issues to other domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, wcf

I have a mail send functionality  from my WCF service using  the following code.
Now I can able to send mail to all email for the same domain. ("mydomain.com") .but I cant able to send the mails to other domains like gmail.com  or yahoo.com. etc.  using mail.mydomain.com". Does anybody solve this or tell me the reason for this?

```
message.From = "admin@mydomain.com";
message.Body = mailInfo.MessageBody;
message.To.Add("test@gmail.com");
message.Subject = "test subject;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
if (mailInfo.Attachment1 != null && mailInfo.Attachment1.Length > 0)
{
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(mailInfo.Attachment1), mailInfo.Attachment1Name));
}

var smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.mydomain.com");
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredentialadmin@mydomain.com, CryptoHelper.Decrypt(adminpassword));
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
object usrtkn = message;
smtp.SendCompleted += smtp_SendCompleted;
smtp.SendAsync(message, usrtkn);
```

Comment: Your mail server is not relaying it's mail to an outbound smtp server?

Comment: Personally I find it more flexible to not include the smtp config in code and instead use you web/app.config file.

Comment: Look at the `<mailsettings>` element for config file http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx

Comment: You could also try http://mailtrap.io if you are unsure if your relay is working correctly - once you sign up it gives you an example config file.